# increase font size of hyperlink text html

Tags: html, css, anchor, font-size

I am working on web application where I have taken *href*. But the default font of it is too small when comparing to the page. So I want to increase the size of the font.

**My output page look like below:**

[image]

I have tried by font size for anchor tag but it doesn't show any effect after the font tag.

**Code I have tried is:**

```
<font size="100px"><a href="selectTopic?html" style="text-decoration: none">HTML 5</a></font>
```

So how can I change the font size?

Comment: `style="text-decoration: none; font-size: 1.5em;"`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
a {font-size: 100px}
```

Try avoid using font tag because it's deprecated. Use CSS like above instead. You can give your anchors specific class and apply any style for them.

Comment: this will change all `a font-size` so better tell hi to use a class or use a child selector instead like `ul.class li a`

Answer (score 16):

Your `font` tag is not correct, so it won't work in some browsers. The `px` unit is used with CSS, not HTML attributes. The font tag should look like this:

```
<font size="100">
```

Well, actually it shouldn't be there at all. The `font` tag is deprecated, you should use CSS to style the content, like you do already with the `text-decoration`:

```
<a href="selectTopic?html" style="font-size: 100px; text-decoration: none">HTML 5</a>
```

To separate the content from the styling, you should of course work towards putting the CSS in a style sheet rather than as inline `style` attributes. That way you can apply one style to several elements without having to put the same `style` attribute in all of them.

Example:

```
<a href="selectTopic?html" class="topic">HTML 5</a>
```

CSS:

```
.topic { font-size: 100px; text-decoration: none; }
```

Answer (score 2):

increase the padding size of font and then try to increase font size:-

```
style="padding-bottom:40px; font-size: 50px;"
```

Answer (score 1):

you can add class in anchor tag also like below

```
.a_class {font-size: 100px}
```

Comment: This answer could be clearer.  While it should be obvious to those who know HTML and CSS, you should specify that the best way to adjust the font would be via CSS rather than a font tag.  It would also help to note that the poster would need to add `class="a_class"` to his HTML.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way simpler way. You put the href in a paragraph just created for that href. For example:

HREF name